# Poser Mesh with openGL 1.0, 50 % of Triangles seem to miss

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I generated a 3D model with Poser to use it with openGL 1.0 in a Android Application. When I render the mesh I can see the 3D Model as generated in Poser 8, but unfortunately only half of the triangles are rendered - it look like I have to draw some kind of squares instead. Is there any method to mirror the existing triangles so I can draw the missing ones?

My mesh is generated from a wavefront object. Therefor I use a class called Mesh

```
public final class Mesh {

public enum PrimitiveType {
    Points,
    Lines,
    Triangles,
    LineStrip,
    TriangleStrip,
    TriangleFan
}

// gl instance
private GL10 gl;

// vertex position buffer, array
private float vertices[];
private int vertexHandle;
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

// color buffer, array
private float colors[];
private int colorHandle;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

// texture coordinate buffer, array
private float texCoords[];
private int texHandle;
private FloatBuffer texBuffer;

// normal (for illumination) buffer, array
private float normals[];
private int normalHandle;
private FloatBuffer normalBuffer;

// index where next vertices will be inserted
private int index = 0;

// number vertices for mesh
private int numVertices = 0;

// renderer support vbos
private boolean globalVBO = true;

// is mesh dirty
private boolean dirty = true;

// last mesh
private static Mesh lastMesh;

// mesh count
public static int numMeshes = 0;

/**
 * after calling constructor first set attribute (color, texture, normal), then fix the vertex by calling vertex(...)
 *
 * @param gl                    GL10
 * @param numVertices           number vertices of mesh
 * @param hasColors             using colors?
 * @param hasTextureCoordinates using textures coordinates
 * @param hasNormals            using normals?
 */
public Mesh(GL10 gl, int numVertices, boolean hasColors, boolean hasTextureCoordinates, boolean hasNormals) {
    this.gl = gl;
    vertices = new float[numVertices * 3];
    int[] buffer = new int[1];

    if (!globalVBO) {
        vertexBuffer = allocateBuffer(numVertices * 3);
    } else {
        ((GL11) gl).glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        vertexHandle = buffer[0];
        vertexBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(vertices);
    }

    if (hasColors) {
        colors = new float[numVertices * 4];

        if (!globalVBO) {
            colorBuffer = allocateBuffer(numVertices * 3);
        } else {
            ((GL11) gl).glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
            colorHandle = buffer[0];
            colorBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(colors);
        }
    }

    if (hasTextureCoordinates) {
        texCoords = new float[numVertices * 2];

        if (!globalVBO) {
            texBuffer = allocateBuffer(numVertices * 3);
        } else {
            ((GL11) gl).glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
            texHandle = buffer[0];
            texBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(texCoords);
        }
    }

    if (hasNormals) {
        normals = new float[numVertices * 3];

        if (!globalVBO) {
            normalBuffer = allocateBuffer(numVertices * 3);
        } else {
            ((GL11) gl).glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
            normalHandle = buffer[0];
            normalBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(normals);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * allocates FloatBuffer of size
 *
 * @param size size number of floats
 * @return FloatBuffer
 */
private FloatBuffer allocateBuffer(int size) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * 4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    return buffer.asFloatBuffer();
}

/**
 * renders mesh given type, starts at offset wirh numVertices vertices
 *
 * @param type        PrimitiveType (see above)
 * @param offset      offset in number of vertices
 * @param numVertices number of vertices to use
 */
public void render(PrimitiveType type, int offset, int numVertices) {
    boolean wasDirty = dirty;
    if (dirty) {
        update();
    }

    if (this == lastMesh && !wasDirty) {
        gl.glDrawArrays(getPrimitiveType(type), offset, numVertices);
        return;
    } else {
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    }

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    if (globalVBO) {
        ((GL11) gl).glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexHandle);
        ((GL11) gl).glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    } else {
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    }

    if (colors != null) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        if (globalVBO) {
            ((GL11) gl).glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
            ((GL11) gl).glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        } else
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
    }

    if (texCoords != null) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        if (globalVBO) {
            ((GL11) gl).glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texHandle);
            ((GL11) gl).glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        } else
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer);
    }

    if (normals != null) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        if (globalVBO) {
            ((GL11) gl).glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalHandle);
            ((GL11) gl).glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        } else
            gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalBuffer);
    }

    gl.glDrawArrays(getPrimitiveType(type), offset, numVertices);
    lastMesh = this;
}

/**
 * renders mesh as given type with numVertices from calling vertex()
 *
 * @param type PrimitveType
 */
public void render(PrimitiveType type) {
    render(type, 0, numVertices);
}

/**
 * returns openGL constant of PrimitiveType
 *
 * @param type PrimitiveType (enum above)
 * @return openGL constant
 */
private int getPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType type) {
    if (type == PrimitiveType.Lines) {
        return GL10.GL_LINES;
    } else if (type == PrimitiveType.Triangles) {
        return GL10.GL_TRIANGLES;
    } else if (type == PrimitiveType.LineStrip) {
        return GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP;
    } else if (type == PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip) {
        return GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP;
    } else if (type == PrimitiveType.Points) {
        return GL10.GL_POINTS;
    } else {
        return GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;
    }
}

/**
 * updates the direct buffers in case the user
 */
private void update() {
    if (!globalVBO) {
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        if (colors != null) {
            colorBuffer.put(colors);
            colorBuffer.position(0);
        }

        if (texCoords != null) {
            texBuffer.put(texCoords);
            texBuffer.position(0);
        }

        if (normals != null) {
            normalBuffer.put(normals);
            normalBuffer.position(0);
        }
    } else {
        GL11 gl = (GL11) this.gl;

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexHandle);
        gl.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.length * 4, vertexBuffer, GL11.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        if (colors != null) {
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
            gl.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.length * 4, colorBuffer, GL11.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        }

        if (normals != null) {
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalHandle);
            gl.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.length * 4, normalBuffer, GL11.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        }

        if (texCoords != null) {
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texHandle);
            gl.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords.length * 4, texBuffer, GL11.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        }

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    numVertices = index;
    index = 0;
    dirty = false;
}

/**
 * defines position of current vertex, before calling call method like color, normal or texCoord
 *
 * @param x x coordinate
 * @param y y coordinate
 * @param z z coordinate
 */
public void vertex(float x, float y, float z) {
    dirty = true;
    int offset = index * 3;
    vertices[offset] = x;
    vertices[offset + 1] = y;
    vertices[offset + 2] = z;
    index++;
}

/**
 * sets color of current vertex
 *
 * @param r red
 * @param g green
 * @param b blue
 * @param a alpha
 */
public void color(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
    dirty = true;
    int offset = index * 4;
    colors[offset] = r;
    colors[offset + 1] = g;
    colors[offset + 2] = b;
    colors[offset + 3] = a;
}

/**
 * sets the normal of current vertex
 *
 * @param x x components
 * @param y y components
 * @param z z components
 */
public void normal(float x, float y, float z) {
    dirty = true;
    int offset = index * 3;
    normals[offset] = x;
    normals[offset + 1] = y;
    normals[offset + 2] = z;

}

/**
 * sets texture coordinates of current vertex
 *
 * @param s s coordinate (correlates x)
 * @param t t coordinate (correlates y)
 */
public void texCoord(float s, float t) {
    dirty = true;
    int offset = index * 2;
    texCoords[offset] = s;
    texCoords[offset + 1] = t;
}

/**
 * deletes all buffers, sets all attributes to null
 */
public void dispose() {
    if (globalVBO) {
        GL11 gl = (GL11) this.gl;
        if (vertexHandle != -1)
            gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, new int[]{vertexHandle}, 0);
        if (colorHandle != -1)
            gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, new int[]{colorHandle}, 0);
        if (normalHandle != -1)
            gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, new int[]{normalHandle}, 0);
        if (texHandle != -1)
            gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, new int[]{texHandle}, 0);
    }

    vertices = null;
    vertexBuffer = null;
    colors = null;
    colorBuffer = null;
    normals = null;
    normalBuffer = null;
    texCoords = null;
    texBuffer = null;
    numMeshes--;

}

/**
 * @return number of vertices
 */
public int getMaximumVertices() {
    return vertices.length / 3;
}

/**
 * resets index
 */
public void reset() {
    dirty = true;
    index = 0;
}

}
```

and a class called MeshLoader

```
public class MeshLoader {
/**
 *
 * Loads a mesh from the given InputStream
 * @param gl GL10 instance
 * @return The mesh
 */
public static Mesh loadObj( GL10 gl, InputStream in )
{
    String line = "";

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) );
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        String l = reader.readLine();
        while( l != null )
        {
            b.append( l );
            b.append( "\n" );
            l = reader.readLine();
        }

        line = b.toString();
        reader.close();
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage() + " " +
                "couldn't load file mesh from input stream" );
    }
    return loadObjFromString( gl, line );
}

/**
 * Loads a mesh from the given string in obj format
 *
 * @param obj The string
 * @return The Mesh
 */
public static Mesh loadObjFromString( GL10 gl, String obj )
{
    String[] lines = obj.split( "\n" );
    float[] vertices = new float[lines.length * 3];
    float[] normals = new float[lines.length * 3];
    float[] uv = new float[lines.length * 3];

    int numVertices = 0;
    int numNormals = 0;
    int numUV = 0;
    int numFaces = 0;

    int[] facesVerts = new int[lines.length * 3];
    int[] facesNormals = new int[lines.length * 3];
    int[] facesUV = new int[lines.length * 3];
    int vertexIndex = 0;
    int normalIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = 0;
    int faceIndex = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ )
    {
        String line = lines[i];
        if( line.startsWith( "v " ) )
        {
            String[] tokens = line.split( " " );
            vertices[vertexIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            vertices[vertexIndex+1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
            vertices[vertexIndex+2] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]);
            vertexIndex += 3;
            numVertices++;
            continue;
        }

        if( line.startsWith( "vn " ) )
        {
            String[] tokens = line.split( " " );
            normals[normalIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            normals[normalIndex+1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
            normals[normalIndex+2] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]);
            normalIndex += 3;
            numNormals++;
            continue;
        }

        // coords of each texture point
        if( line.startsWith( "vt" ) )
        {
            String[] tokens = line.split( " " );
            uv[uvIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            uv[uvIndex+1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
            uvIndex += 2;
            numUV++;
            continue;
        }

        if( line.startsWith( "f " ) )
        {
            String[] tokens = line.split( " " );

            String[] parts = tokens[1].split("/");
            facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
            facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
            facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
            faceIndex++;

            parts = tokens[2].split("/");
            facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
            facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
            facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
            faceIndex++;

            parts = tokens[3].split("/");
            facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
            facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
            facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
            faceIndex++;
            numFaces++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(gl, numFaces * 3, false ,numUV > 0, numNormals > 0  );

    for( int i = 0; i < numFaces*3; i++ )
    {
        if( numNormals > 0 )
        {
            int normalIdx = facesNormals[i] * 3;
            mesh.normal( normals[normalIdx], normals[normalIdx+1], normals[normalIdx+2] );
        }
        if( numUV > 0 )
        {
            int uvIdx = facesUV[i] * 2;
            mesh.texCoord( uv[uvIdx], uv[uvIdx+1]);
        }

        int vertexIdx = facesVerts[i] *3;
        mesh.vertex( vertices[vertexIdx], vertices[vertexIdx+1], vertices[vertexIdx+2] );
    }

    return mesh;
}

private static int getIndex( String index, int size )
{
    if( index == null || index.length() == 0 )
        return 0;
    int idx = Integer.parseInt( index );
    if( idx < 0 )
        return size + idx;
    else
        return idx - 1;
}

}
```

every 3D Object is a Mesh and will be generated by the MeshLoader.loadObject Method.

This works perfectly with simple Objects. But not with 3D Models generated by Poser 8.

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I triangulated the Mesh and reduced the number of vertices under 32.000. Therefor I exported the Mesh from Poser as Collada-File and imported it to Blender (because there are more tutorials :D).